# How to Clear / Enable the 'Don't Show Again for This Site" setting in win 8 / ie 10

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I accidently clicked the 'Don't show again for this site' button in IE 10 - how can I reset this option?!

[image: Add-on error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the only way to reset this is to remove the entry from the registry!  BACK IT UP FIRST!!

The value can be found in the registry under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\DisableRequiresActiveXPrompt
```

Here's a command line code to delete the entry

```
reg delete "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v DisableRequiresActiveXPrompt
```